# Serialize/deserialize "NHibernate Session", lazy inicialization error ("StateServer mode" for clustering)

Tags: c#, nhibernate, serialization, cluster-computing, spring.net

I use in my application a kind of "session-per-conversation" pattern implementation. 
In this approach the "NHibernate Session" is kept on the "HTTP Session". In every "Http Request" the "NHibernate Session" is reconnected at the beginning and disconnected at the end of the request. The "NHibernate Session" is kept in "HTTP Session" by the end of the "conversation". This is working very well.

**The Problem:**

Now I'm considering using ["StateServer mode"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx) on the "Http Session".
Thus, all objects in the "HTTP Session" must be serializable, including the "NHibernate Session".

So I'm doing a proof of concept to validate that the serialization/deserialization of a "NHibernate Session" and its cached objects works.

The "proof of concept" is the following unit test. And the goal is to make it pass.

Code:

```
/*069*/  [Test]
/*070*/  public void Test()
/*071*/  {
/*072*/      //for inspecting the SQL commands
/*073*/      NhSqlLogCapture hhSqlLogCapture = new NhSqlLogCapture();
/*074*/  
/*075*/      MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
/*076*/  
/*077*/      ISession sessionBefore = null;
/*078*/      ISession sessionAfter = null;
/*079*/  
/*080*/      //querying before the serialization.
/*081*/      try
/*082*/      {
/*083*/          sessionBefore = this.sessionFactory.OpenSession();
/*084*/          sessionBefore.FlushMode = FlushMode.Auto;
/*085*/  
/*086*/          hhSqlLogCapture.Enable();
/*087*/  
/*088*/          //Querying only 'DetailEtt'
/*089*/          hhSqlLogCapture.SqlStatments.Clear();
/*090*/          ICriteria crt = sessionBefore.CreateCriteria<DetailEtt>();
/*091*/          crt
/*092*/              .SetFetchMode("Master", FetchMode.Select);
/*093*/          IList<DetailEtt> cen1DetailList = crt.List<DetailEtt>();
/*094*/  
/*095*/          //BEGIN: Serializing
/*096*/          //also serializing an instance of 'DetailEtt' to verify that keeps only one instance to the same database record.
/*097*/          sessionBefore.Disconnect();
/*098*/          Object[] serializationArray = new object[] { sessionBefore, sessionBefore.Get<DetailEtt>(1) };
/*099*/          BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
/*100*/          bf.Serialize(ms, serializationArray);
/*101*/          //END: Serializing
/*102*/  
/*103*/          //assertions
/*104*/          //Checking the sql command executed.
/*105*/          Assert.AreEqual(1, hhSqlLogCapture.SqlStatments.Count, "hhSqlLogCapture.SqlStatments.Count");
/*106*/          Regex rx = new Regex("(?is).*SELECT.*FROM.*DETAIL.*");
/*107*/          Assert.IsTrue(rx.IsMatch(hhSqlLogCapture.SqlStatments[0]), hhSqlLogCapture.SqlStatments[0]);
/*108*/  
/*109*/          hhSqlLogCapture.Disable();
/*110*/      }
/*111*/      finally
/*112*/      {
/*113*/          sessionBefore = null;
/*114*/      }
/*115*/  
/*116*/      try
/*117*/      {
/*118*/          //BEGIN: Deserializing
/*119*/          BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
/*120*/          ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
/*121*/          Object[] deserializationArray = (Object[])bf.Deserialize(ms);
/*122*/          DetailEtt dtEttDeserialized = (DetailEtt)deserializationArray[1];
/*123*/          sessionAfter = (ISession)deserializationArray[0];
/*124*/          //BEGIN: Deserializing
/*125*/  
/*126*/          IDbConnection conn = this.dbProvider.CreateConnection();
/*127*/          conn.Open();
/*128*/          sessionAfter.Reconnect(conn);
/*129*/  
/*130*/          //Enabling again because the session loses the reference to the log (I think).
/*131*/          hhSqlLogCapture.Enable();
/*132*/          hhSqlLogCapture.SqlStatments.Clear();
/*133*/  
/*134*/          DetailEtt dtEtdSSGet = sessionAfter.Get<DetailEtt>(1);
/*135*/          MasterEtt mtEtd = dtEtdSSGet.Master;
/*136*/          Console.WriteLine(mtEtd.Description);
/*137*/  
/*138*/          //assertions
/*139*/          //Checking the sql command executed.
/*140*/          Assert.AreEqual(1, hhSqlLogCapture.SqlStatments.Count, "hhSqlLogCapture.SqlStatments.Count");
/*141*/          Regex rx = new Regex("(?is).*SELECT.*FROM.*MASTER.*");
/*142*/          Assert.IsTrue(rx.IsMatch(hhSqlLogCapture.SqlStatments[0]), hhSqlLogCapture.SqlStatments[0]);
/*143*/          //verify that keeps only one instance to the same database record
/*144*/          Assert.AreSame(dtEttDeserialized, dtEtdSSGet, "verify that keeps only one instance to the same database record");
/*145*/      }
/*146*/      finally
/*147*/      {
/*148*/          sessionAfter.Close();
/*149*/      }
/*150*/  }
```

The test passes on almost everything. But it fails when tries to load an entity that is "Lazy".

The error:

```
SofPOC.Questions.SerializeSession.SerializeSessionTest.Test:
  NHibernate.LazyInitializationException : Initializing[SofPOC.Questions.SerializeSession.Entities.MasterEtt#5]-Could not initialize proxy - no Session.    em NHibernate.Proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.Initialize()
at NHibernate.Proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.Initialize()
at Spring.Data.NHibernate.Bytecode.LazyInitializer.Invoke(IMethodInvocation invocation) in c:\_prj\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Data.NHibernate21\Data\NHibernate\Bytecode\LazyInitializer.cs:line 101
at Spring.Aop.Framework.AbstractMethodInvocation.Proceed() in c:\_prj\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Aop\Aop\Framework\AbstractMethodInvocation.cs:line 284
at Spring.Aop.Framework.DynamicProxy.AdvisedProxy.Invoke(Object proxy, Object target, Type targetType, MethodInfo targetMethod, MethodInfo proxyMethod, Object[] args, IList interceptors) in c:\_prj\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Aop\Aop\Framework\DynamicProxy\AdvisedProxy.cs:line 208
at DecoratorAopProxy_9872659265c04d36bc9738f2aaddfb08.get_Description()
at SofPOC.Questions.SerializeSession.SerializeSessionTest.Test() in C:\Users\hailtondecastro\lixo\stackoverflow\dotnet\StackoverflowNetPOCs_20120718\src\SofPOC.Net4.NH2.Spring13.2010\Questions\SerializeSession\SerializeSessionTest.cs:line 136
```

DetailEtt:

```
[Serializable]
public class DetailEtt
{
    private Int32? id;
    /// <summary>
    /// PK
    /// </summary>
    public virtual Int32? Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    private String description;
    /// <summary>
    /// TODO:
    /// </summary>
    public virtual String Description
    {
        get { return description; }
        set { description = value; }
    }

    private MasterEtt master;
    /// <summary>
    /// TODO:
    /// </summary>
    public virtual MasterEtt Master
    {
        get { return master; }
        set { master = value; }
    }
}
```

MasterEtt:

```
[Serializable]
public class MasterEtt
{
    private Int32? id;
    /// <summary>
    /// PK
    /// </summary>
    public virtual Int32? Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    private String description;
    /// <summary>
    /// TODO:
    /// </summary>
    public virtual String Description
    {
        get { return description; }
        set { description = value; }
    }
}
```

DetailEtt.hbm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="SofPOC.Questions.SerializeSession.Entities" assembly="SofPOC.Net4.NH2.Spring13">
  <class name="DetailEtt" table="DETAIL">
    <id name="Id" type="Int32">
      <column name="ID" sql-type="INTEGER"></column>
      <generator class="assigned"></generator>
    </id>
    <property name="Description" type="String">
      <column name="DESCRIPTION" sql-type="VARCHAR( 100 )"></column>
    </property>
    <many-to-one name="Master" fetch="select">
      <column name="MS_ID" sql-type="INTEGER"></column>
    </many-to-one>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

MasterEtt.hbm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="SofPOC.Questions.SerializeSession.Entities" assembly="SofPOC.Net4.NH2.Spring13">
  <class name="MasterEtt" table="MASTER">
    <id name="Id" type="Int32">
      <column name="ID" sql-type="INTEGER"></column>
      <generator class="assigned"></generator>
    </id>
    <property name="Description" type="String">
      <column name="DESCRIPTION" sql-type="VARCHAR( 100 )"></column>
    </property>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**The Question:**

Even after reconnecting the deserialized "Hibernate Session" I get "Lazy Load Error". How to avoid this kind of "Lazy Load Error" without having to reattach the entities?

I'm using:

- Spring.Net 1.3.2
- NHibernate 2.1.2
- System.Data.SQLite 1.0.80.0

The complete source is here: [Q11553780.7z](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/49510149/stackoverflow/dotnet/Q11553780.7z)

**NOTES:**

- Before opening the solution (".\ Src\SofPOC.2010.sln") run ".\Dependencies\setup.bat" to load dependencies.
- See ".\readme.txt" and ".\dependencies\readme.txt" for instructions about the dependencies.

**EDITED:**

I found that the cause of the problem is in the class `NHibernate.Proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer` of NHibernate. The field `_session` is marked as `[NonSerialized]`. This makes this field not be serialized. Consequently it is null after deserialization.

See the code:

```
namespace NHibernate.Proxy
{
    [Serializable]
    public abstract class AbstractLazyInitializer : ILazyInitializer
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// If this is returned by Invoke then the subclass needs to Invoke the
        /// method call against the object that is being proxied.
        /// </summary>
        protected static readonly object InvokeImplementation = new object();

        private object _target = null;
        private bool initialized;
        private object _id;
        [NonSerialized]
        private ISessionImplementor _session;
        ...
```

**EDITED 2:**

The cause of the problem is really the attribute [NonSerialized] because when I make the following "hack" the test passes. By Reflection, I make a change on the attributes of the "_session" from "Private | NotSerialized" to only "Private".

The hack:

```
    protected override void OnSetUp()
    {
        //Hacking "_session"
        Type aliType = Type.GetType("NHibernate.Proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer, NHibernate");
        FieldInfo fiSession = aliType.GetField("_session", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
        FieldInfo fi_m_fieldAttributes =
            fiSession.GetType().GetField(
                "m_fieldAttributes", 
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic 
                    | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
        // changing it from "Private | NotSerialized" to only "Private"
        fi_m_fieldAttributes.SetValue(fiSession, FieldAttributes.Private);

        base.OnSetUp();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there are three options to try:

1. Use reflection to set the _session field with the deserialized session
2. Open an new session an reattach them. This might be a pain to do, but I think that if the NHibernate team makes it difficult to do something, they probably have a good reason for it.
3. Create your own ILazyInitializer. The ServerSide has an article about it [here](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1363571/Remote-Lazy-Loading-in-Hibernate). I haven't tried it myself.

If you try nr 1, let us know if it works. I'm interested to see what happens. Theoretically it should work.

Comment: thanks for the help. I want to test the three options. I have a consideration to do: aboult "...even if it wasn't marked NonSerializable.". I think you are mistaken at that point. Using reflection I made a hack in the FieldInfo of "_session" changing it from "Private | NotSerialized" to only "Private". And it worked.

Comment: the third solution seems more attractive. The first solution seems a little impractical because I would have to identify instances that are "dynamic proxies", but I agree it works. The second solution is exactly what I want to avoid, that's why I'm using the "session-per-conversation" pattern.

Comment: Now that I read my answer again in daylight, "If you deserialize a session, it doesn't magically appear in that _session field (even if it wasn't marked NonSerializable).' doesn't make any sense so I removed it from the answer.

Answer (score 1):

**This is my own answer following the suggestion by @Jeroen:**

I chose the third suggestion given by @Jeroen: "Create your own ILazyInitializer..." (It worked). 
Demonstration:

Below is the way it was made:

SerializeSessionTest.spring.config (changes on 'MySessionFactory'):

```
<object id="MySessionFactory" type="Spring.Data.NHibernate.LocalSessionFactoryObject, Spring.Data.NHibernate21">
  <property name="DbProvider" ref="DbProvider"/>
  <property name="MappingResources">
    <list>
      <value>assembly://SofPOC.Net4.NH2.Spring13/SofPOC.Questions.SerializeSession.Entities/MasterEtt.hbm.xml</value>
      <value>assembly://SofPOC.Net4.NH2.Spring13/SofPOC.Questions.SerializeSession.Entities/DetailEtt.hbm.xml</value>
    </list>
  </property>
  <property name="HibernateProperties">
    <dictionary>
      <!--<entry key="connection.provider" value="AcessaDados.NHibernate.Connection.SiefDriverConnectionProvider, AcessaDados"/>-->
      <entry key="dialect" value="NHibernate.Dialect.SQLiteDialect"/>
      <entry key="connection.driver_class" value="NHibernate.Driver.SQLite20Driver"/>
      <entry key="current_session_context_class" value="Spring.Data.NHibernate.SpringSessionContext, Spring.Data.NHibernate21"/>

      <entry key="hbm2ddl.keywords" value="none"/>
      <entry key="query.startup_check" value="false"/>
      <entry key="show_sql" value="true"/>
      <entry key="format_sql" value="true"/>
      <entry key="use_outer_join" value="true"/>
      <entry key="bytecode.provider" value="SofPOC.Questions.SerializeSession.Spring.Data.NHibernate.Bytecode.BytecodeProviderSrlzSupport, SofPOC.Net4.NH2.Spring13"/>
      <entry key="proxyfactory.factory_class" value="SofPOC.Questions.SerializeSession.Spring.Data.NHibernate.Bytecode.ProxyFactoryFactorySrlzSupport, SofPOC.Net4.NH2.Spring13"/>
    </dictionary>
  </property>
</object>
```

LazyInitializerSrlzSupport.cs (Here was made ILazyInitializer implementation that supports the ISessionImplementor serialization):

```
/// <summary>
/// Here was made ILazyInitializer implementation that supports the ISessionImplementor serialization.
/// </summary>
[Serializable]
public class LazyInitializerSrlzSupport : 
    global::Spring.Data.NHibernate.Bytecode.LazyInitializer,
    global::NHibernate.Proxy.ILazyInitializer, 
    AopAlliance.Intercept.IMethodInterceptor
{
    private static readonly MethodInfo exceptionInternalPreserveStackTrace;

    static LazyInitializerSrlzSupport()
    {
        exceptionInternalPreserveStackTrace = typeof(Exception).GetMethod("InternalPreserveStackTrace", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// TODO:
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="entityName"></param>
    /// <param name="persistentClass"></param>
    /// <param name="id"></param>
    /// <param name="getIdentifierMethod"></param>
    /// <param name="setIdentifierMethod"></param>
    /// <param name="componentIdType"></param>
    /// <param name="session"></param>
    public LazyInitializerSrlzSupport(
        string entityName, 
        Type persistentClass, 
        object id, 
        MethodInfo getIdentifierMethod, 
        MethodInfo setIdentifierMethod, 
        IAbstractComponentType componentIdType, 
        ISessionImplementor session)
        :base(entityName, 
            persistentClass, 
            id, 
            getIdentifierMethod, 
            setIdentifierMethod, 
            componentIdType, 
            session)
    {
        this._sessionSrlzSupport = session;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This must be the trick. This will be serialized so that 
    /// we can load the session in the "dynamic proxy".
    /// </summary>
    private ISessionImplementor _sessionSrlzSupport;

    #region ILazyInitializer Members
    public new void Initialize()
    {
        if (this.Session == null)
        {
            this.Session = this._sessionSrlzSupport;
        }
        base.Initialize();
    }

    public new object GetImplementation()
    {
        this.Initialize();
        return base.Target;
    }

    #endregion

    #region IMethodInterceptor Members

    object IMethodInterceptor.Invoke(IMethodInvocation invocation)
    {
        try
        {
            MethodInfo methodInfo = invocation.Method;
            object returnValue = base.Invoke(methodInfo, invocation.Arguments, invocation.Proxy);

            if (returnValue != InvokeImplementation)
            {
                return returnValue;
            }

            SafeMethod method = new SafeMethod(methodInfo);
            return method.Invoke(this.GetImplementation(), invocation.Arguments);
        }
        catch (TargetInvocationException ex)
        {
            exceptionInternalPreserveStackTrace.Invoke(ex.InnerException, new Object[] { });
            throw ex.InnerException;
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

BytecodeProviderSrlzSupport.cs:

```
/// <summary>
/// TODO:
/// </summary>
public class BytecodeProviderSrlzSupport : 
    global::Spring.Data.NHibernate.Bytecode.BytecodeProvider,
    global::NHibernate.Bytecode.IBytecodeProvider
{
    private IProxyFactoryFactory proxyFactoryFactory;
    /// <summary>
    /// TODO:
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="listableObjectFactory"></param>
    public BytecodeProviderSrlzSupport(IListableObjectFactory listableObjectFactory)
        : base(listableObjectFactory)
    {
        this.proxyFactoryFactory = new ProxyFactoryFactorySrlzSupport();
    }

    #region IBytecodeProvider Members


    IProxyFactoryFactory IBytecodeProvider.ProxyFactoryFactory
    {
        get { return this.proxyFactoryFactory; }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

ProxyFactoryFactorySrlzSupport.cs:

```
/// <summary>
/// TODO:
/// </summary>
public class ProxyFactoryFactorySrlzSupport : 
    global::NHibernate.Bytecode.IProxyFactoryFactory
{
    #region IProxyFactoryFactory Members

    /// <summary>
    /// Build a proxy factory specifically for handling runtime lazy loading. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The lazy-load proxy factory.</returns>
    public IProxyFactory BuildProxyFactory()
    {
        return new ProxyFactorySrlzSupport();
    }

    ///<summary>
    ///</summary>
    public IProxyValidator ProxyValidator
    {
        get { return new DynProxyTypeValidator(); }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

ProxyFactorySrlzSupport.cs:

```
/// <summary>
/// TODO:
/// </summary>
public class ProxyFactorySrlzSupport : 
    global::Spring.Data.NHibernate.Bytecode.ProxyFactory
{
    private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(ProxyFactorySrlzSupport));

    [Serializable]
    private class SerializableProxyFactory : global::Spring.Aop.Framework.ProxyFactory
    {
        // ensure proxy types are generated as Serializable
        public override bool IsSerializable
        {
            get { return true; }
        }
    }

    public override global::NHibernate.Proxy.INHibernateProxy GetProxy(object id, global::NHibernate.Engine.ISessionImplementor session)
    {
        try
        {
            // PersistentClass = PersistentClass.IsInterface ? typeof(object) : PersistentClass
            LazyInitializer initializer = new LazyInitializerSrlzSupport(EntityName, PersistentClass,
                                                  id, GetIdentifierMethod, SetIdentifierMethod, ComponentIdType, session);

            SerializableProxyFactory proxyFactory = new SerializableProxyFactory();
            proxyFactory.Interfaces = Interfaces;
            proxyFactory.TargetSource = initializer;
            proxyFactory.ProxyTargetType = IsClassProxy;
            proxyFactory.AddAdvice(initializer);

            object proxyInstance = proxyFactory.GetProxy();
            return (INHibernateProxy)proxyInstance;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error("Creating a proxy instance failed", ex);
            throw new HibernateException("Creating a proxy instance failed", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

The complete source is here: [Q11553780.7z](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/49510149/stackoverflow/dotnet/Q11553780.7z)